# A question regarding whether a continuous function on $\mathbb T$ can be holomorphically extended to whole $\mathbb D- \mathbb T.$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $f \in C(\mathbb T)$, the set of all continuous maps on unit circle ,be such that all the negative Fourier co-efficients of $f$ are all $0.$ Then, can $f$ be extended holomorphically to whole $\mathbb D- \mathbb T?$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ The converse is true .
Indeed, if $f \in C(\mathbb T)$ can be extended holomorphically to whole $\mathbb D- \mathbb T$ , then by Cauchy's Integral formula, we can get that all negative Fourier co-effs of $f$ vanishes .

But, for the question, $f$ is orthogonal to $\{e^{in \theta} | n<0\}$ ; and I can't think of any $g \in C(\mathbb T)$ with $g$ can't be holomorphically extended to whole $\mathbb D- \mathbb T.$

A small hint is warmly appreciated, thanks in advance .

Comment: Let $g$ be the Poisson integral of $f$. The Fourier series for the Poisson kernel leads to a power series for $g$...

Comment: I am just a beginner in learning Fourier Analysis, would be very helpful if you explain your comment a little bit. I don't know Poisson Integral .

Comment: If $f=\sum a_n e^{int}, n \ge 0$ then extend as $f(z)= \sum a_nz^n$